# Regex to match number in #define statement

Tags: regex

I have a line like this:

```
#define PROG_HWNR "36084"
```

or this:

```
#define PROG_HWNR "#37595"
```

I'd like to extract the number (and increase it, but that's not the matter here)

I wrote a regex, but it's not working (at least in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ )

```
(?<="#?)(.*?)(?=")
```

I also tried variations like

```
(?<=("#?))(.*?)(?=")
```

or

```
(?<=("|"#)))(.*?)(?=")
```

But no success. The problem is, that I want to match *only* the number, no matter if there is a # or not ...

Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks!!

Comment: Why are you complicating things with lookahead/behind ? [POC](http://regex101.com/r/jG3jX9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
"#?(\d+)"$
```

It will match:

```
"   a quote
#?  optional hash
(   (start capturing)
\d+ one or more digits
)   (stop capturing)
"   a quote
$   anchor to end
```

**[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcdUR/), and [here is a RegExr](http://regexr.com?354bo)**

Comment: Thank you very much - unfortunately this also matches the " and the # which it shouldn't. That's why I used the lookahead and lookbehind

Comment: @MichaelNiemand No it doesn't. Did you see the fiddle? Or the RegExr? It captures the number in the capture group #1.

Comment: my apologies, you are right. Thanks again! I havent figured out, if capturing groups are available. I will do that

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the variable length of the lookbehind. Only few regex engines can deal with this. Because there are only two possible lookbehinds (including the `#` or not), you can expand that into two lookbehinds:

```
(?:(?<="#)|(?<=")).*?(?=")
```

Note that you don't need to capture the `.*?` if you use lookarounds, as they are excluded from the match anyway. Also, a better way than using non-greedy `.*?` is to use a greedy expression that can never go past the ending delimiter:

```
(?:(?<="#)|(?<="))[^"]*(?=")
```

Alternatively (if you can access captured submatches), you can use a capturing approach and get rid of the lookarounds:

```
"#?([^"]*)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^#define \w+ "#?(\d+)"$
```

That will match the whole line, with the first/single group being the number you are looking for.

This is actually pretty basic regex functionality: match an optional character (`?`) and match a group of characters (the parentheses).

You can even go one simpler:

```
\d+
```

will match a string of digits. Only the digits. And ignore the rest of the input string.

Use this tool for testing this stuff, I found it pretty handy: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx